# Revision history says these two questions are deleted, but they still exist

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, revisions-list

While playing around with some SEDE queries, I came across the following two odd questions (both from the same user):

- 758706: [Insert matching parentheses xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758706/insert-matching-parentheses-xcode) ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/758706/revisions))
- 1101705: [Input Manager in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101705/input-manager-in-cocoa) ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1101705/revisions))

Both of these questions, according to the revision history, were deleted but never undeleted, and yet the questions exist on the site. These are the *only* two questions like this.

The *PostHistory* table entries for these two questions are:

```
postid   name           creationdate         userdisplayname 
-------  -------------  -------------        --------------- 
758706   Initial Title  2009-04-17 01:47:01  Saurabh Sharan  
758706   Initial Body   2009-04-17 01:47:01  Saurabh Sharan  
758706   Initial Tags   2009-04-17 01:47:01  Saurabh Sharan  
758706   Post Deleted   2009-10-23 19:39:22  Saurabh Sharan  

1101705  Initial Title  2009-07-09 03:28:37  Saurabh Sharan  
1101705  Initial Body   2009-07-09 03:28:37  Saurabh Sharan  
1101705  Initial Tags   2009-07-09 03:28:37  Saurabh Sharan  
1101705  Edit Title     2009-07-09 04:07:36  null            
1101705  Post Deleted   2009-10-23 19:38:47  Saurabh Sharan
```

What's up with these two questions? How did they end up this way, shouldn't they be in a deleted state?

Comment: Does it mean the user was deleted, and so her deletions were undone?

Comment: @Tim I don't know but surely there would be more than two questions in the whole SO database like this if that were the case, no?

Comment: Hu, good point.

Comment: Your first example is now outdated, sadly.